# Highchart waterfall with json result column issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, waterfall

i'm new in the use of highchart, and i made a jquery to display an json result in the series data, but the problem is that i can't (or at least don't know how to) set the last column in x-axis 0

```
            success: function (datalist) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(datalist))
                //comienza el chart
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'waterfall',
                        width: 1000,
                        height: 500

                    },

                    title: {
                        text: name
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category',
                        labels: {
                            rotation: -45,
                            style: {
                                fontSize: '16px',
                                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    },

                    legend: {
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        enabled: false
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '<b>${point.y:,.2f}</b> USD'
                    },

                    series: [{
                        upColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                        data: datalist.tablas,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            formatter: function () {
                                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / 1000, ',') + 'k';
                            },
                            style: {
                                color: '#FFFFFF',
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                textShadow: '0px 0px 3px black'
                            }
                        },
                        pointPadding: 0
                    }]
                });
```

with this code, the data from the json is displayed, but the problem is that the last one should be at x-axis 0 like the first one and is displayed as an increment,  i found there is a way you get the last column with the property **isSum: true**, but i neither know how to add more columns when i already have the serie's data filled with the json result, hope you can help me to understand better the use of the highchart, thanks in advice

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution, like i said, with the atribute: issum:true, i just add another object in the json array with this line code

```
 success: function (datalist) {
 datalist['tablas'].push({ "name": fyear, "isSum": "true" });
```

with that we get a last column with the sum of the previous values, hope this help anybody with the same issue